# Using the logged in users username or user id as a variable in Joomla 3

Tags: joomla-3.x

Is it possible to query the user id or username of a logged in user in PHP/Joomla 3 and assign that to a variable? If so how?

Im trying to create user specific content. Specifically some graphs which are held in a location whos path includes reference to a directory with the same name as their site user id.

If I can pull their user id and assign that to a variable I can then create a path to their own specific content using the contents of the variable specific to them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to get the ID of the currently logged in user. In which case, you can simply use the following:

```
$id = JFactory::getUser()->id;
```

Comment: Keep in mind that guests will return an empty string when asking for an ID.

Comment: So cool, many thanks. Can this be dropped into an article for example?

Comment: @PaulaLivingstone - Yes, I can be put in an article, however you'll need to use a 3rd party extension to allow PHP inside an article. Sourcerer would be a good one to use.